# How can I read Log(...) from guest (virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox

In sources of virtualbox (in folder Additions for example) we can see many strings:
Log(...)
But how can we see it when virtualbox is running? Maybe it write in file "Log"? But I can't found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Vbox-log you need:

1) To add in AutoConfig.kmk

```
 VBOX_WITH_R0_LOGGING := 1
```

2) Compile with

```
kmk BUILD_TYPE=debug
```

3) Then,
you should set environment variable

```
VBOX_LOG (what kind of module you want to see in your log)  
VBOX_LOG_FLAGS  
VBOX_LOG_DEST (location of log)
```

more info there : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VBoxLogging
And after it you should run VirtualBox from this terminal window.

3 - For example

```
export VBOX_LOG_DEST="dir=/home/guest/tmp"  
export VBOX_LOG=hgcm.e.l.f  
export VBOX_LOG_FLAGS="buffered thread msprog" (optionaly)
```